# Getting error neo4j [not found] when trying to generate a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, generator, neo4j

I installed JRuby and the neo4j gem and trying to use a generator to create a model:

```
jruby -S rails generate scaffold User name:string born:date --orm=neo4j
```

However, I get this error:

```
error  neo4j [not found]
```

I tried installing neo4j through bundler and just gem install. Either way, `which neo4j` returns nothing.

I tried this with the the neo4j-rails gem as well but I the neo4j rubyforge page says it is no longer needed. I also tried just generating a model rather than a scaffold.

Is this error specific to just generators or does it mean that my neo4j installation didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your installation did not work.

The problem is that you have probably installed version 0.4.6 which is not specific to the JRuby platform but also installs (incorrectly) on MRI. So the error 'neo4j [not found]' is because you are using JRuby and installed the neo4j.rb gem in MRI. Neo4j.rb version >= 1.0.0 can only be installed on JRuby.

I recommend using RVM:

1. rvm install jruby
2. rvm use jruby
3. gem install bundler
4. bundle install

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did install jruby using rvm (jruby-1.6.3). How do I make sure to install Neo4j.rb version >= 1.0.0 and not version 0.4.6? I tried gem 'neo4j', ">= 1.0.0," but I get "could not find gem 'neo4j (>= 1.0.0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile".